# Использование DirectX в C#

Tags: c#, directx

Написал программу на C# (квадрат из 8 точек, повороты, масштабирование, сброс). Теперь нужно переделать её под DirectX, о котором я вообще ничего не знаю... Я даже не знаю как его подключать, могли бы вы посоветовать очень простую лекцию для выполнения этого простого задания...

Comment: все у меня получилось.... вроде не плохо... 
Но! D3DPT_POINTLIST рисует только пиксель!... как в DX рисовать элипс или окружность)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключить DX функции для создания графики можно установив пакет DirectX SDK который можно скачать с оффсайта Microsoft. А переделать под него - означает использовать в качестве функции рисования API DX'а(DirectDraw), самый банальный способ на мой взгляд и простой это написать ту же программу юзая Microsoft Visual C++, там вывод графики осуществляется по средствам DirectDraw.

Это довольно обширная тема чтобы описать все этапы тут, ведь нам потребуется написать процедуру вызова окна, инициализации палитры и много чего другого, поэтому поделюсь ссылкой на ресурс который помог мне в этом разобраться.

http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/games/directx/ddraw/directx.htm

Comment: Спасибо! надеюсь успею до завтра разабраться и написать)

Answer (score 1):

раз на С# то может надо переделать на Direct2D, а не DirectX?
вот [библиотека](http://direct2dsharp.codeplex.com/)

а если все таки на DirectX, то есть смысл скачать себе XNA Game Studio, там все можно сделать в 10 строчек

Answer (score 1):

На С# есть замечательная библиотека SharpDX

Основной код(Код шейдера ниже)

```
    // Copyright (c) 2010-2013 SharpDX - Alexandre Mutel
// 
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
// 
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// 
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Windows;
using Buffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer;
using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;

namespace MiniCube
{
    /// <summary>
    /// SharpDX MiniCube Direct3D 11 Sample
    /// </summary>
    internal static class Program
    {
  //      [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            var form = new RenderForm("SharpDX - MiniCube Direct3D11 Sample");

            // SwapChain description
            var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,
                ModeDescription =
                    new ModeDescription(form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height,
                                        new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
                IsWindowed = true,
                OutputHandle = form.Handle,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };

            // Used for debugging dispose object references
            // Configuration.EnableObjectTracking = true;

            // Disable throws on shader compilation errors
            //Configuration.ThrowOnShaderCompileError = false;

            // Create Device and SwapChain
            Device device;
            SwapChain swapChain;
            Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, desc, out device, out swapChain);
            var context = device.ImmediateContext;

            // Ignore all windows events
            var factory = swapChain.GetParent<Factory>();
            factory.MakeWindowAssociation(form.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

            // Compile Vertex and Pixel shaders
            var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCube.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0");
            var vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, vertexShaderByteCode);

            var pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("MiniCube.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0");
            var pixelShader = new PixelShader(device, pixelShaderByteCode);

            var signature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vertexShaderByteCode);
            // Layout from VertexShader input signature
            var layout = new InputLayout(device, signature, new[]
                    {
                        new InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 0, 0),
                        new InputElement("COLOR", 0, Format.R32G32B32A32_Float, 16, 0)
                    });

            // Instantiate Vertex buiffer from vertex data
            var vertices = Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, new[]
                                  {
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Front
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // BACK
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Top
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),

                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), // Bottom
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Left
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),

                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), // Right
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                                      new Vector4( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f), new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
                            });

            // Create Constant Buffer
            var contantBuffer = new Buffer(device, Utilities.SizeOf<Matrix>(), ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);



            // Prepare All the stages
            context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout;
            context.InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
            context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(vertices, Utilities.SizeOf<Vector4>() * 2, 0));
            context.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(0, contantBuffer);
            context.VertexShader.Set(vertexShader);
            context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);

            // Prepare matrices
            var view = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0, 0, -5), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitY);
            Matrix proj = Matrix.Identity;

            // Use clock
            var clock = new Stopwatch();
            clock.Start();

            // Declare texture for rendering
            bool userResized = true;
            Texture2D backBuffer = null;
            RenderTargetView renderView = null;
            Texture2D depthBuffer = null;
            DepthStencilView depthView = null;

            // Setup handler on resize form
            form.UserResized += (sender, args) => userResized = true;

            // Setup full screen mode change F5 (Full) F4 (Window)
            form.KeyUp += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
                        swapChain.SetFullscreenState(true, null);
                    else if (args.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
                        swapChain.SetFullscreenState(false, null);
                    else if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
                        form.Close();
                };

            // Main loop
            RenderLoop.Run(form, () =>
            {
                // If Form resized
                if (userResized)
                {
                    // Dispose all previous allocated resources
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref backBuffer);
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref renderView);
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref depthBuffer);
                    Utilities.Dispose(ref depthView);

                    // Resize the backbuffer
                    swapChain.ResizeBuffers(desc.BufferCount, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, Format.Unknown, SwapChainFlags.None);

                    // Get the backbuffer from the swapchain
                    backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);

                    // Renderview on the backbuffer
                    renderView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);

                    // Create the depth buffer
                    depthBuffer = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription()
                    {
                        Format = Format.D32_Float_S8X24_UInt,
                        ArraySize = 1,
                        MipLevels = 1,
                        Width = form.ClientSize.Width,
                        Height = form.ClientSize.Height,
                        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
                        Usage = ResourceUsage.Default,
                        BindFlags = BindFlags.DepthStencil,
                        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None,
                        OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None
                    });

                    // Create the depth buffer view
                    depthView = new DepthStencilView(device, depthBuffer);

                    // Setup targets and viewport for rendering
                    context.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, 0.0f, 1.0f));
                    context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthView, renderView);

                    // Setup new projection matrix with correct aspect ratio
                    proj = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 4.0f, form.ClientSize.Width / (float)form.ClientSize.Height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

                    // We are done resizing
                    userResized = false;
                }

                var time = clock.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0f;

                var viewProj = Matrix.Multiply(view, proj);

                // Clear views
                context.ClearDepthStencilView(depthView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
                context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.Black);

                // Update WorldViewProj Matrix
                var worldViewProj = Matrix.RotationX(time) * Matrix.RotationY(time * 2) * Matrix.RotationZ(time * .7f) * viewProj;
                worldViewProj.Transpose();
                context.UpdateSubresource(ref worldViewProj, contantBuffer);

                // Draw the cube
                context.Draw(36, 0);

                // Present!
                swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
            });

            // Release all resources
            signature.Dispose();
            vertexShaderByteCode.Dispose();
            vertexShader.Dispose();
            pixelShaderByteCode.Dispose();
            pixelShader.Dispose();
            vertices.Dispose();
            layout.Dispose();
            contantBuffer.Dispose();
            depthBuffer.Dispose();
            depthView.Dispose();
            renderView.Dispose();
            backBuffer.Dispose();
            context.ClearState();
            context.Flush();
            device.Dispose();
            context.Dispose();
            swapChain.Dispose();
            factory.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Код шейдера

```
    // Copyright (c) 2010-2013 SharpDX - Alexandre Mutel
// 
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
// 
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// 
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
struct VS_IN
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
};

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
};

float4x4 worldViewProj;

PS_IN VS( VS_IN input )
{
    PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

    output.pos = mul(input.pos, worldViewProj);
    output.col = input.col;

    return output;
}

float4 PS( PS_IN input ) : SV_Target
{
    return input.col;
}
```

[SharpDX MiniCube Direct3D 11 Sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct3D11/MiniCube) (лицензия MIT)